# static page with multiple loops breaks post pagination

Tags: loop, pagination

**I have a static page which runs two loops but pagination doesn't work on the second loop.**

1. The first loop shows the static content of the page
2. The second loop shows the last 3 blog posts

Pagination shows up, adds /page/2 to the url but it always shows just the same 3 posts.
Why doesn't this work as expected?

***First loop: display the static content***

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
endwhile; endif;
```

***Second loop: shows the last 3 posts and pagination***

```
global $more;
$more = 0;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array('post_type'=>'post','post_status'=>'publish','showposts'=>3,'paged'=>$paged));

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;

next_posts_link();
previous_posts_link();
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the `$paged` variable, at least not in the code posted.

[Per the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters), you need to do something like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

... before trying to use the `$paged` variable. That is, it needs to come before this line:

```
 $wp_query->query(array('post_type'=>'post','post_status'=>'publish','showposts'>3,'paged'=>$paged));
```

Also, side note, what is this-- `php the_content();` ? That is going to trigger an error. Why do you have the `php` there?

Comment: thank you, I removed the "php".I've added that code and yes, I forgot it but it doesn't work either. The url on the pagination element remains /page/2 but it just doesn't work!